# ASP.NET Core Task<IActionResult> cannot return NotFound() and OK() without async

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This function gives an error:

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<IActionResult> Something (string value)
{
     Student student = new Student();
     if (value == "LOW")
     {
         return NotFound();
     }

     return Ok();
}
```

This function works fine:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Something (string value)
{
     Student student = new Student();
     if (value == "LOW")
     {
         return NotFound();
     }
     return Ok();
}
```

When I am trying to `return NotFound();` or `return Ok();` when I am not including keyword `asnyc` before `Task` as shown above, it gives me error. However, when i added the `async` keyword in front of `Task`, it does not shows any error in the compiler. Can you tell me what is causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `async` keyword tells the compiler that while the method returns a `Task`, the code within the method is expected to run in an asynchronous manner and internally `await` something.  The compiler will look for one or more `await`s and modify the structure of the method to wrap functionality around tasks and continuations of tasks.  So ultimately the compiler will wrap the returned result in a `Task<T>` for you.

Basically, your logic can focus on the value you want to return, rather than focus on the structure of asynchronicity.  The `async` and `await` keywords exist to make that part simpler.

So *both* of these methods actually have a problem:

1. The first method is not `async`, so the compiler isn't expecting to modify it in any way.  Instead, the compiler is expecting it to return what it says it will return, which is a `Task<IActionResult>`.  It doesn't return that, so the compiler produces an error.
2. The second method is `async`, but nowhere in that method do you `await` anything.  The compiler can make this work, but produces a warning that nothing is being awaited in this `async` method.

So both are wrong.  Since your method doesn't do anything asynchronous, don't make it `async`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Something(string value)
{
    Student student = new Student();
    if (value == "LOW")
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

You only need to make the method `async` (and wrap a `Task<T>` around the return type) if the method internally needs to `await` something.

Comment: I essentially said the same thing (we both must have answered same minute)...but your answer is nicer, so upvoting this one.  Looks like I beat you by 1 second .. but you took longer to type!  haha

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want async...then your (first) code should be:

```
 public   IActionResult Something (string value)
```

(no Task)